# CustomConsoleComponents metadata not including lookup component

Tags: metadata-api, custom-console-components

```
    <customConsoleComponents>
    <primaryTabComponents>
        <containers>
            <region>Right</region>
            <sidebarComponents>
                <componentType>VisualForcePage</componentType>
                <height>100</height>
                <page>MBOSystem</page>
                <unit>Percentage</unit>
            </sidebarComponents>
            <style>Stack</style>
            <unit>Percentage</unit>
            <width>30</width>
        </containers>
        <containers>
            <region>Left</region>
            <sidebarComponents>
                <componentType>Lookup</componentType>
                <height>100</height>
                <lookup>ThisLead</lookup>
                <unit>Percentage</unit>
            </sidebarComponents>
            <style>Stack</style>
            <unit>Percentage</unit>
            <width>20</width>
        </containers>
    </primaryTabComponents>
</customConsoleComponents>
```

The second container was not included when I pulled the file using the IDE. I believe it's because there is no value to set for the lookup tag. It's supposed to reference the current record - in that case the current lead, but I don't know the value to enter for it to do so. Does anyone know what value I could put there or why the second container wasn't retrieved?

Comment: I've confirmed the metadata for the container referencing a self-lookup console component wasn't retrieved because it is a self-reference. We had a container with a lookup to a related record which was deployed, so it's only self-referencing lookups. Looking at the [MetaData API doc for layout](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_layouts.htm#SidebarComponent), you can see the field 'lookup' is looking for a SF field name - any ideas on what field name is used for the record to reference itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed at some point. When pulling the metadata, I now retrieve a value of 'self_lookup_component'.

```
<containers>
  <isContainerAutoSizeEnabled>true</isContainerAutoSizeEnabled>
     <region>Left</region>
     <sidebarComponents>
        <componentType>Lookup</componentType>
        <lookup>self_lookup_component</lookup>
     </sidebarComponents>
     <style>Stack</style>
     <unit>Percentage</unit>
     <width>20</width>
</containers>
```